# In Domino Designer, what is the best approach for drawing a rectangle on a Form based on the user's input?

Tags: graphics, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I created a Form that prompts the user to choose values for four fields.

1. Width  (an integer from 1 to 10)
2. Length (an integer from 1 to 10)
3. Area   (a color from a color picker)
4. Border (a color from a color picker)

After the user has supplied all 4 values, I want to display the rectangle on the same Form in real-time so the user can see how it looks.

What is the best approach for accomplishing this and how could I implement it?

Note: I am using IBM Domino Designer 10.0.1FP3.

Comment: This doesn't sound possible to me in the Notes client.  What is the rectangle representing?  If you could limit the number of colours and width and length then you could maybe look at hide-when formula.  You will be able to do some javascript if it is for a web form.

Comment: @RobMason The rectangle represents nothing beyond a shape the user can control to some extent. This is a programming exercise I came up with so I can get some experience in Domino Designer. I can limit the number of colors and width and length by using pre-set values in combo-boxes. Aren't hide-when formulas just for Xpages? My goal is to have this functionality available in the client and through the server.

Answer (score 2):

I think your two options will be...

- Embedding a Java applet on the form and using Java's graphics capabilities to draw the rectangle,

Or

- Calling third-party vendor Genii Software and talking to Ben about whether this can be done with the MIDAS Rich Text API. (Something in the back of my mind tells me that he did a demo of something like this once.)

Comment: You may also be able to use a browser control.